# Returning two user input strings to main using pointers

Tags: c

I am trying to figure out the proper syntax to returned two scanned strings so that I can use them in main using pointers.

```
void get_user_info(char* user_string_one[20] , char* user_string_two[20]) {
char string_one[20] = "";
char string_two[20] = "";

string_one = "hello";
string_two = "goodbye";

*user_string_one = string_one;
*user_string_two = string_two;

return;
}

int main(void) {
char user_string_one[20] = "";
char user_string_two[20] = "";

get_user_info(user_string_one[20], user_string_two[20]);

printf("%s %s\n", user_string_one, user_string_two);

return 0;
}
```

I am sure I am making a really simple mistake, I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Bluntly, pretty much nothing you have above is correct and you really just need to learn C. I'm sorry if that sounds harsh.

Comment: Thats not how you initialize char arrays..

Comment: For starters, you cannot assign a string with `string_one = "hello";` where `string_one` is an array. You must either have the correct initialisation when it is defined (`char string_one[20] = "hello";`) or use `strcpy`.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void get_user_info(char* user_string_one, char* user_string_two)
{
    strcpy(user_string_one, "hello");
    strcpy(user_string_two, "goodbye");
}

int main(void)
{
    char user_string_one[20];
    char user_string_two[20];

    get_user_info(user_string_one, user_string_two);

    printf("%s %s\n", user_string_one, user_string_two);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings can't be passed around that way in C.  When an array is passed to a function as an argument, the function receives a pointer to the first element only.  A pointer is not an array.

You need to use functions in the standard header `<string.h>` to copy data in strings.  For example;

```
#include <string.h>

void get_user_info(char* user_string_one , char* user_string_two)
{
        strcpy(user_string_one, "hello");
        strcpy(user_string_two, "goodbye");
} 

int main(void)
{
    char user_string_one[20] = "";
    char user_string_two[20] = "";

    get_user_info(user_string_one, user_string_two);

    printf("%s %s\n", user_string_one, user_string_two);

    return 0;
}
```

Bear in mind that a string literal, like `"hello"`, is represented as an array of `char`, with a terminating `'\0'` (a `char` with value zero) appended (a marker representing the end).   So `"hello"` is represented in memory using the six characters `'h'`, `'e'`, `'l'`, `'l'`, `'o'`, and `'\0'`.   `strcpy()` and similar functions ASSUME strings are provided in that form and relies on destination arrays (the ones being copied to) being long enough to hold everything up to and including the `'\0'` marker.